# How do I save a JSON object as an array then pass it to a React component?

Tags: json, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

Essentially, I want to do this:

```
var PRODUCTS = []

fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/10scuq')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => PRODUCTS = data)

const container = document.getElementById('root')

render (
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS}/>,
  container
)
```

Instead of doing this:

```
const PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The first snippet of code ends up passing an empty array to the component, the second works.

I do not want to use this.setState(). I do not want to touch the inside of the component at all. Is there anyway else to do it while using fetch()?

Comment: "I do not want to use this.setState()" there's no way then (other than lifecycle method + forceUpdate() which is terrible). In React, component must be re-rendered to display the updated data.

Comment: You are using React but you don't want to use state and you don't want to touch the component itself. Good luck with that :) Maybe there is a way but I'm pretty sure it will be an ugly and not, very not recommended one. Try to think with React way if you are using React.

Comment: The second snippet of code was pulled straight from the React docs. this.setState() wasn't used to pass PRODUCTS to the FilterableProductTable component. I figured if I can console.log(data) after fetch(), there must be a way to convert the JSON object into an array that I can pass to FilterableProductTable without using this.setState.

Comment: Which doc is this? You can pass a static data to a component like in the second snippet but you want to do an async operation. Before your fetch is completed your component is rendering already. So, how will you re-render again when your data changes? This is done with state changes in React. I'm a learner and trying to stick in React way, not getting around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly way of doing this :) As told in the comments think the React way if you are using React.

```
var PRODUCTS = []

fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/10scuq')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => { PRODUCTS = data; renderMe() })

const container = document.getElementById('root')

const renderMe = () => {
  render(
    <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

renderMe();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try pushing your data into the `PRODUCTS` array

```
var PRODUCTS = []
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/10scuq')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => PRODUCT.push(data)
);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem and pushing a whole array to another one.